# Remove All Adjacent Duplicates in String (Leet Code 1209)

Tags: c++

You are given a string s and an integer k, a k duplicate removal consists of choosing k adjacent and equal letters from s and removing them, causing the left and the right side of the deleted substring to concatenate together.

We repeatedly make k duplicate removals on s until we no longer can.

Return the final string after all such duplicate removals have been made. It is guaranteed that the answer is unique.

following the code that I wrote.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string removeDuplicates(string s, int k) {
        stack<pair<char,int>> st;
        string str;
        int idx = 0;
        st.push({s[idx++],1});
        while(idx < s.size()){
            if(st.empty()) {
                st.push({s[idx++],1});
                continue;
            }
            pair<char,int> p = st.top();
            if(p.first == s[idx]){
                if(p.second < k-1){
                    p.second++; // problem point
                        idx++;
                }
                else {
                    st.pop();
                    idx++;
                }
            }
            else{
                st.push({s[idx++],1});
            }
        }
        while(!st.empty()){
            pair<char,int> p = st.top();
            st.pop();
            str.push_back(p.first);
        }
        reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
        return str;
    }
};
```

for example input string is aabbbc and int is 3. correct output is aac but my output is abc.
so I debugged that code. I think problem is "pair<char,int> p = st.top();".
Is initializing p the problem? but I don't understand what is wrong.
when fourth index of aabbbc is b, p.second is 2.
but in next loop p.second isn't remember. p.second is 1.
what's the problem?

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages. If you ask a question about code written in C++ then please don't add the C language tag.

Comment: Your `p` local variable is reset each time you pop a character from the stack, so incrementing the counter has no effect and your code simply reduces any repetitive sequence to a single character. But even if you fix this, a stack is a wrong choice of data structure. Actually, you need no data structure at all, just a linear scan of your input string. I suggest you rethink your algorithm on a sheet of paper, in simple pseudo-code, instead of letting C++ drag you into this mess.